# <compatible-screens> for galaxy note

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I developed an application for galaxy note which uses the S pen. I would like to make it available only for galaxy note. my understanding is that the galaxy note has a large, xhdpi screen.

I added this in my androidmanifest.xml :

```
<compatible-screens>
  <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

but when I publish it, the gt-n7000 (galaxy note) appears as incompatible because of my manifest.
I tried some other combinations of compatible-screens but it still shows the galaxy note as incompatible.

in fact I even tried this (minsdkversion=3 and all screens compatibles) and the note is still marked incompatible... :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.testnote.testnote"
        android:versionCode="10012"
        android:versionName="1.0.12">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
            android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
    <compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>-
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="testtest"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

removing the screen filter makes the galaxy note compatible but I just can't remove all devices one by one...

Comment: was this using a stock ROM? i ran into a similar problem that the AT&T Galaxy Note had a leaked ICS ROM, which reports the screensize as 'normal' instead of 'large'. The only way to get it to work was to allow the 'normal' screensize, which of course allowed 800+ devices. In the end I unchecked 890 of 898 devices - which is really stupid. 
There should be a way to select the specific devices you want to target rather than just selecting those you want to exclude. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only want to enable one device, you're better off manually selecting it (by model name) in the market admin page.